# Secure webapi 2 without authorisation or user login

Tags: c#, security, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I looked everywhere for an answer about securing my webApi but always i'm pointed to OAuth or openID, but i don't want the user to login or authenticate. This is my problem:

I have a webapi which is called via Javascript to get the data in Json. This data is used in the Html of that page. (deployed on Azure)

Now i don't want someone else to get that data via Javascript or with a simple GET request. Only my html page is allowed to do so.

I'm looking for something to secure my Webapi to be only consumed by the applications i want. If i look to the OAuth and Azure stuff, people always have to login, but i want this page to be public, but only the webapi needs to be secure.

I can't check on IP, because the call is done at client side in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to authenticate and thus secure the API to be used by a specific client (run entirely in the browser - like SPAs) app. You cannot protect the data the app sends to the API. (see for more details [Protecting REST API behind SPA against data thiefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800405/protecting-rest-api-behind-spa-against-data-thiefs))

You could build some modules server side and then use some token based server to server communication if you do not want to introduce users and end user authentication.

Of course it is also a question of how you interpret security.

- If it is just that you do not want other web apps to use the data -
  CORS policies will do the job. It is unlikely that there will be more
  than some isolated cases of users using a browser other than the
  popular once which respect CORS.
- If it is you do not want data to be mass downloaded you could
  implement some client filtering based on IP. This could even be done
  on the networking layer so the API do not need to be modified in any
  way.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can have it secured making sure the request has some headers defined by you. For example, you can set an Authorization header with a token that only you know. You can for example, create a token based on a key that you and the webapi share, encrypt it with the time you are calling the api. The web api receives the request and:

1 - Check if the request has the token it requires;

2 - if it does, it creates a token the same way your page did;

3 - matches its token with the requests token;

If you are calling the webapi via javascript, the method may be exposed. However, it's one idea

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), it may be your solution. 
In synthesis you can allow requests to the Api only from some specific websites. Most, nearly all browsers, support it.

This is how you enable and configure it in [Web Api 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Comment: CORS is also client based, it can be bypassed.

A browser will prevent a malicious website from querying the API of another website on my behalf (because the query is client-side).

For example let say Gmail has an API to get the list of emails, I could add a javascript code to a website that fetches that api and save the result in a database. If you go on this website, it will try to query the list of your emails, because you are the one logged into Gmail. In that case, Your browser will save you!